# Chrome headless download pdf

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara, google-chrome-headless

I've got a script which downloads a pdf from a site which keeps updating every month and I want to automate this. It works but I cannot get it to work headless and I think it's because it's not handling the downloads correctly. It seems to start the chrome in headless ok and my navigation commands seem to work, but when it goes to download nothing happens.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
require 'capybara'
require 'rb-inotify'
require 'webdrivers/chromedriver'

def initialise
  Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, options: chrome_options)
  end
  @session = Capybara::Session.new(:chrome)
end

# Settings and profile for the Chrome Browser
# NOTE: still cannot get headless working
def chrome_options
  opts = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  opts.add_argument('--headless') unless ENV['UI']
  opts.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  opts.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
  opts.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
  opts.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')

  opts.add_preference(:download,
                      directory_upgrade: true,
                      prompt_for_download: false,
                      default_directory: "~/Downloads")

  opts.add_preference(:plugins,
                      plugins_disabled: ["Chrome PDF Viewer"])

  opts.add_preference(:browser, set_download_behavior: { behavior: 'allow' })
  opts
end
```

**Update** I'm using Chrome version 81.0.4044.113-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Across different versions of Chrome and selenium-webdriver the settings required to get downloads working have changed/grown.  It looks like you're missing one of them.

```
opts.add_preference('download.default_directory', '~/Downloads')
```

Another thing you can also do, depending on versions, is

```
def initialise
  Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, options: chrome_options).tap do |driver|
      driver.browser.download_path = '~/Downloads'
  end
  @session = Capybara::Session.new(:chrome)
end
```

Comment: Did you try one vs the other, or everything at once? Also try using an absolute path rather than one including ~

Comment: Thanks the first option worked with an absolute path

Answer (score 0):

I added some configurations to your code, probably it will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
require 'capybara'
require 'rb-inotify'
require 'webdrivers/chromedriver'

def initialise
  Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, options: chrome_options)
  end
  @session = Capybara::Session.new(:chrome)
end

# Settings and profile for the Chrome Browser
# NOTE: still cannot get headless working
def chrome_options
  download_directory = "~/Downloads"
  opts = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  opts.add_argument('--headless') unless ENV['UI']
  opts.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  opts.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
  opts.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
  opts.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')

  opts.add_preference(:download,
                      directory_upgrade: true,
                      prompt_for_download: false,
                      default_directory: download_directory)
  opts.add_preference(:browser, set_download_behavior: { behavior: 'allow' })

  driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome,
                                          options: options)
  bridge = driver.browser.send(:bridge)

  path = '/session/:session_id/chromium/send_command'
  path[':session_id'] = bridge.session_id

  bridge.http.call(:post, path, cmd: 'Page.setDownloadBehavior',
                   params: {
                       behavior: 'allow',
                       downloadPath: download_directory
                   })
  driver
  opts.add_preference(:plugins,
                     always_open_pdf_externally: true)

  opts.add_preference(:browser, set_download_behavior: { behavior: 'allow' })
  opts
end
```

Comment: Tried adding the bridge http call and this didn't fix the problem. The script doesn't download the pdf, it's still ike Chrome is not downloading it or the script is waiting at a dialog box.

Comment: I just forgot something on my code, you should create variable "download_directory", or replace with your directory at: 
      downloadPath: download_directory

I use this configs with other type of files on my automation, I'll try with pdf and get back with results.

Comment: I tested with a script that google an PDF file and click on first result to download it, and it worked, and preference of disabling PDF plugin has no difference on my test.
Also, without headless, it only worked with this argument:
`opts.add_preference(:plugins,
                         always_open_pdf_externally: true)`
disabling plugin has no effect.

Comment: I updated the code of answer, but if you still having issue, I can update answer with how exactly is on my env file (it's little bit different, because I use cucumber)